# Methods vs functions: unexpected unit return value

Tags: scala, methods

Why does the method below return a unit value (i.e., `()`) when the equivalent function returns a boolean (as expected)?

```
// aMethod(1) returns ()
def aMethod(a: Int) { true }

// aFunction(1) returns true
val aFunction = (a: Int) => true
```

Comment: You don't need to use any of your `return`s or curly brackets - they just add noise to the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will add this just for clarity:

```
def aMethod(a: Int) {
  true
}
```

This returns `Unit`.

```
def aMethod(a: Int) = {
  true
}
```

This returns `Boolean`. (inferred by the compiler)

The thing is, you **MUST HAVE** a `=` after the signature of your method to make it return something different than `Unit`. When you have a `=`, the return type will be inferred by the compiler, depending on the last expression in your method-body.

Answer (score 5):

Lets add an explicit return type of `Boolean` to your method:

```
def aMethod(a: Int): Boolean
{
    return true
}
```

Now we have a compiler error:

```
Error:(120, 5) illegal start of declaration (possible cause: missing `=' in front of current method body)
    return true
    ^
```

Oops, lets try doing what it says:

```
def aMethod(a: Int): Boolean =
{
    return true
}
```

Now our method returns a `Boolean` rather than `Unit`.

So your issue is the abuse of `return` and inappropriate method syntax. If you do not have an `=` in the method declaration then the return type is assumed to be `Unit`.

Lets tidy your code a bit more:

```
object X {
  def aMethod(a: Int) = true

  val aFunction = (a: Int) => true

  def test(f: Int => Any) = (1 to 5) map f foreach println
}
```

I have removed the `return` - I wrote [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480660/why-is-the-use-of-return-a-bad-habit-in-scala/23480812#23480812) as to why you should not use it. I have removed the superfluous curly brackets.

I have also changed your `for` loop into a more Scala like comprehension.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the feedback :-) The sample is a little messier than strictly needed on purpose, since I was in parallel writing some findings on returns, etc. But what I want to know is not how to make it work or how to make it prettier, but WHAT is going on under the hood to explain the behavior :-S Also, does not that "Scala like" syntax require intermediate memory?

Comment: @Daniel I explained what was going on under the hood. Your method was of type `Unit` because of inappropriate syntax. What do you mean by `intermediate memory`? I think readability trumps whatever minor memory benefits in this case.

Comment: Ok found the issue. I voted your answer up since it has valuable insights, but I'll add the answer I was looking for below, for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's tidy your code as @Boris did.

```
object X {
  def aMethod(a: Int) = true

  val aFunction = (a: Int) => true

  def test(f: Int => Any) = (1 to 5) map f foreach println
}
X.test(X.aFunction)
X.test(X.aMethod)
```

In scala, method and function are different concepts. Method just like java method, it belongs to a class and can have generic type. However, function is instance of `Function` class in scala, so it's an object.

We can use "function" as method parameter because it's an object but we can't use "method" to do the same thing.

What happened to `X.test(X.aMethod)` is "eta-expansion", it converts `X.test(X.aMethod)` to `X.test(i => X.aMethod(i))`. So the parameter is still a "function".

Updated:

You can corroborate this by put the code into "try.scala" and run "scala -Xprint:type try.scala"