# Fibonacci memoization in Scala with Memo.mutableHashMapMemo

Tags: scala, fibonacci, scalaz, memoization

I am trying implement the fibonacci function in Scala with memoization

One example given here uses a case statement:
[Is there a generic way to memoize in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257378/is-there-a-generic-way-to-memoize-in-scala/39425517#39425517)

```
import scalaz.Memo
lazy val fib: Int => BigInt = Memo.mutableHashMapMemo {
  case 0 => 0
  case 1 => 1
  case n => fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
}
```

It seems the variable `n` is implicitly defined as the first argument, but I get a compilation error if I replace `n` with `_`

Also what advantage does the `lazy` keyword have here, as the function seems to work equally well with and without this keyword.

However I wanted to generalize this to a more generic function definition with appropriate typing

```
import scalaz.Memo
def fibonachi(n: Int) : Int = Memo.mutableHashMapMemo[Int, Int] {
    var value : Int = 0
    if( n <= 1 ) { value = n; }
    else         { value = fibonachi(n-1) + fibonachi(n-2) }
    return value
}
```

but I get the following compilation error

```
cmd10.sc:4: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Int
 required: Int
def fibonachi(n: Int) : Int = Memo.mutableHashMapMemo[Int, Int] {
                                                                         ^Compilation Failed
Compilation Failed
```

So I am trying to understand the generic way of adding adding a memoization annotation to a scala `def` function

Comment: Your "generalization" actually makes the definition much worse in more ways than one: using mutable state for no reason, risking  integer overflows ... Your immediate problem is that you are trying to assign the result of `mutableHashMapMemo.apply` (which is a function) to an `Int` ... but that's probably not worth solving for the reasons I mentioned above.

Comment: The more general question I am trying to ask is how to take a pre-existing `def` function and add a mutable/immutable memoization annotation/wrapper to it inline.

What would be the correct way to write `def fibonachi(n: Int) : Int` as a memoized function (without using a case statement)?

Comment: The correct way is the first snippet you showed. Case statement is idiomatic scala, and the best to express the definition in this case, but if you for some reason wanted to get rid of, it would look something like `{ n => if(n <= 1) n else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)}`

Comment: @Dima I think the OP is confused between the definition of the `fib` function itself and the definition of the `apply` function inside `Memo.mutableHashMapMemo`

Comment: @OP your variable declaration, `if ... else` then `return` is very un-idiomatic. Very _Java_ even. May I suggest you read [my answer about `if` in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23480812/2071828)?

Comment: "_It seems the variable `n` is implicitly defined as the first argument_". Nope. `n` is the variable in the case when the input is not `0` or `1`. Might I suggest some reading around [Pattern Matching in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html). Either way, you cannot replace `n` with `_` because then `n` is not captured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve a Fibonacci sequence is via a recursive `Stream`.

```
val fib: Stream[BigInt] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1:BigInt)(_+_)
```

An interesting aspect of streams is that, if something holds on to the head of the stream, the calculation results are auto-memoized. So, in this case, because the identifier `fib` is a `val` and not a `def`, the value of `fib(n)` is calculated only once and simply retrieved thereafter.

However, indexing a `Stream` is still a linear operation. If you want to memoize that away you could create a simple memo-wrapper.

```
def memo[A,R](f: A=>R): A=>R =
  new collection.mutable.WeakHashMap[A,R] {
    override def apply(a: A) = getOrElseUpdate(a,f(a))
  }

val fib: Stream[BigInt] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1:BigInt)(_+_)
val mfib = memo(fib)
mfib(99)  //res0: BigInt = 218922995834555169026
```

Answer (score 3):

> The more general question I am trying to ask is how to take a pre-existing `def` function and add a mutable/immutable memoization annotation/wrapper to it inline.

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in Scala unless you are willing to use a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) for this which feels like an overkill to me or to use some very ugly design.

The contradicting requirements are "`def`" and "inline".  The fundamental reason for this is that whatever you do inline with the `def` can't create any new place to store the memoized values (unless you use a macro that can re-write code introducing new `val`/`var`s). You may try to work this around using some global cache but this IMHO falls under the "ugly design" branch.

The design of ScalaZ `Memo` is used to create a `val` of the type `Function[K,V]` which is often written in Scala as just `K => V` instead of `def`. In this way the produced `val` can contain also the storage for the cached values. On the other hand syntactically the difference between usage of a `def` method and of a `K => V` function is minimal so this works pretty well. Since the Scala compiler knows how to convert `def` method into a function, you can wrap a `def` with `Memo` but you can't get a `def` out of it. If for some reason you need `def` anyway, you'll need another wrapper `def`.

```
import scalaz.Memo

object Fib {

  def fib(n: Int): BigInt = n match {
    case 0 => BigInt(0)
    case 1 => BigInt(1)
    case _ => fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
  }

  // "fib _" converts a method into a function. Sometimes "_" might be omitted 
  // and compiler can imply it but sometimes the compiler needs this explicit hint 
  lazy val fib_mem_val: Int => BigInt = Memo.mutableHashMapMemo(fib _) 

  def fib_mem_def(n: Int): BigInt = fib_mem_val(n)

}

println(Fib.fib(5))
println(Fib.fib_mem_val(5))
println(Fib.fib_mem_def(5))
```

Note how there is no difference in syntax of calling `fib`, `fib_mem_val` and `fib_mem_def` although `fib_mem_val` is a value. You may also try this example [online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qFxT4mg1Ta6wQMTrjMfqVg)

**Note**: beware that some ScalaZ `Memo` implementations are not thread-safe.

As for the `lazy` part, the benefit is typical for any `lazy val`: the actual value with the underlying storage will not be created until the first usage. If the method will be used anyway, I see no benefits in declaring it as `lazy`